# Concrete formula for Shapiro's Lemma

Tags: finite-groups, group-cohomology

I wonder if there is a concrete formula to express the isomorphism in the well known Shapiro's Lemma that $H^i(G, \text{CoInd}_{H}^{G}(M)) \simeq H^i(H, M)$, where $H \subset G$ is a subgroup of $G$, $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[H]$-module, and $\text{CoInd}_{H}^{G}(M)$ is the co-induced $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module. Here by 'concrete' I mean, for instance, given an $i$-cocycle $\phi \in Z^i(H, M)$ considered as a map $\phi: H \times \cdots \times H \longrightarrow M$, I wish to find a corresponding cocycle in $Z^i(G, \text{CoInd}_{H}^{G}(M))$, or vice versa.

Comment: Let $\pi: \text{Coind}^G_H(M) = Hom_H(\mathbb{Z}G,M)\to M,\, x \mapsto x(1)$. The isomorphism $\varphi: H^\ast(G,\text{Coind}^G_H(M)) \to H^\ast(H,M)$  from Shapiro's lemma can be described in the following way: Let $f: G \times \cdots \times G \to Hom_H(\mathbb{Z}G,M)$ be a cocycle. Then $\varphi([f])$ is represented by the cocycle $\pi \circ f: H \times \cdots \times H \to M$ (see Brown, Cohomology of Groups, III.8, exercise 2).

Comment: It's more interesting to define the inverse and to show that they compose on cocycle level to the identity up to a coboundary.

Comment: A related question: http://mathoverflow.net/a/256208/7709.

Comment: @tj_: Could you explain what the inverse is?

Answer (score 1):

D. Naidu constructs an explicit inverse map $H^n(H,A) \rightarrow H^n(G,\operatorname{CoInd}_G^H(A))$ for the case $n=1,2$. For the construction and proof, check out lemma 2.1, 2.2 in his paper [Categorical Morita equivalence for group-theoretical categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605530).